# I want to trigger a server side event on textbox enter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to trigger a server side event on textbox enter in asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="Button2_Click"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Send" />
```

Getting error: Unhandled exception at line 31, column 87 in http://localhost:61421/Default.aspx
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Button2_Click' is undefined

[click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOYdh.png)

Comment: When using WebForms, You must differentiate between server-side events (which are handled by the code running on the server) and client-side events (handled by JavaScript code running in the user's browser).
In this case, You defined ```Button2_Click``` server side method and tried to assign it to a client-side event of the textbox. The function ```Button2_Click``` does exist on the server-side, not the client-side, so it could not be found.

Comment: If You want to call server-side event from JavaScript, You can try using method described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx

Comment: Also look into Page Methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the below code works for me "putting my code under a panel with attribute "DefaultButton""

And my toltal coding

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Button2_Click">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="Button2_Click"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Send" />     
</asp:Panel>
```

Thankyou Wazz